# How to resolve many packages being held back after "apt-get upgrade" during Debian 10 upgrade?

Tags: debian, apt, dist-upgrade

I'm currently upgrading one of my Debian 9/KDE machines and have around 1000 packages being held back after running `sudo apt-get upgrade` -> should I run `sudo apt full-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install [~1000 packages]` (how?) or something else?

[Here](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/mips/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrading-full) it says:

> New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install status of another package will be left at their current version (displayed as “held back”). This can be resolved by either using **aptitude** to choose these packages for installation or by trying **apt install *package***.

after the `apt full-upgrade` step.

In some stackexchange answers on related questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) it says that running `apt-get dist-upgrade` can be dangerous during a upgrade when packages have been held back and instead recommend using other more cautious methods than just running `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade` even though [this old page](https://debian-administration.org/article/69/Some_upgrades_show_packages_being_kept_back) at debian-administration.org says that to fix this problem one should run `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

When I run `sudo apt upgrade` (not in the official guide) instead of `sudo apt-get upgrade` it only shows 1 package having unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the release notes say, the next step after running

```
apt-get upgrade
```

([section 4.4.4](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade)) is to run a full upgrade with

```
apt full-upgrade
```

([section 4.4.5](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrading-full)). This should resolve the conditions which resulted in the packages being held back with the minimal upgrade, notably by removing obsolete packages and installing new dependencies: `apt-get upgrade` only upgrades already-installed packages, whereas `apt full-upgrade` will remove and add packages as necessary as well as upgrading packages.

If `apt-get` can’t resolve the situation, it will tell you about it before upgrading anything. There’s not much point in worrying about what *could* happen before you try it; the section you’re referring to is useful if you do run into problems upgrading.

Comment: Isn't `full-upgrade` the `apt` command, and `dist-upgrade` the `apt-get` one?

Comment: @muru both are supported by both commands. I’ll update my answer to match the release notes though.